# custom php email settings?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have this logic

```
    $subject = "something.com Signup - 
    Please do not reply to this email. It was automatically generated.";
    $body = "A new person has signed up to receive something updates:";
    $headers  = "From: webinquiries@something.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: something@gmail.com\n";
    // $headers .= 'Bcc: something@something.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
    mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

which seems ok but one thing.... can i set the smtp info like this

```
 server="smtp.something.net",
 username="webinquiries@somthing.com",
 password="asda.1sda",
 port="587"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the server in php.ini, but user\password as php's build in mail does not support authentication. you should look at a third party library ([phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)) as the php mail() function's very under powered.

Comment: You might note that SMTP is only available on Win32. But yes, a third party tool is really the way to go. There's a Mail module available from PEAR as well that does a lot of this stuff.